# Why does my variables dont take the value in the function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, function, geolocation

I want to display on screen the var longitude en latitude but I think that the function is executing last and I'am stuck with the initial values.
The objective is to print on screen the exact values of the geolocation that the browser returns.
Thanks !!!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>


<head>

<script>
var longitude = "10";
var latitude = "20";
</script>




</head>
<html>
<body  onload="getLocation()">


<script>
var longitude = "30";
function getLocation() {

    if (navigator.geolocation) {
            navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position){
                latitude = position.coords.latitude;
                longitude = position.coords.longitude;
                alert('aaab:' +longitude);
    });
    }else {
                   alert("Geolocation API is not supported in your browser.");
    }
    }

</script>



<script>
alert("ccc");
document.write (longitude);
document.write (latitude);

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

i know that it's working within the function, but there is any way to use those variable outside? I just want to be able to store them in one global variable that cand be called wherever. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

document.write is being executed before your code that updates it is being run. You need to do the document.write in the callback like so:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
  <head>
    <script type='text/javascript'>
      var longitude = "10";
      var latitude = "20";

      function getLocation() {
        if (navigator.geolocation) {
          navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position){
            latitude = position.coords.latitude;
            longitude = position.coords.longitude;

            document.write(latitude+" / "+longitude);  
          });
        }else{
          alert("Geolocation API is not supported in your browser.");
        }
      }

    </script>
  </head>
  <body onload="getLocation()">

  </body>
  </html>
```

Comment: i know that it's working within the function, but there is any way to use those variable outside? I just want to be able to store them in one global variable that cand be called wherever. Thanks

Comment: The global variables *are* being set to latitude and longitude. Your problem is simply that it doesn't happen till after where your original document.write were operating. For clarity of the point: http://jsfiddle.net/Asvjg/

Answer (score 0):

The Geolocation Callback probably hasn't been called at the time you write your longitude and latitude. Maybe you can use jQuery to write the correct values to the screen...

```
<script>
    var longitude = "30";
    function getLocation() {

        if (navigator.geolocation) {
            navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position){
                latitude = position.coords.latitude;
                longitude = position.coords.longitude;
                //alert('aaab:' +longitude);

                // Use jQuery to write your values to the html
                $("#longitude").html(longitude);
                $("#latitude").html(latitude);
            });
        }else {
            alert("Geolocation API is not supported in your browser.");
        }
    }

</script>

<html>
    ...
    <body onload="getLocation()">
        <div id="longitude"></div>
        <div id="latitude"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Correct, the call to `getCurrentPosition()` is asynchronous. The browser uses some clues (like your IP address) to query a geolocation service (like Google). A quick solution is to put your `document.write()` statements inside the callback you define. I'll edit this answer to show that. I was typing my own, but @Syjin beat me :)

Comment: And you beat me again, sir :)

Comment: I know it works like you said, I have the "  alert('aaab:' +longitude);  "  working fine, but I need to use those variables outside the function.

Comment: You can use them wherever you like. You just have to wait until `getCurrentPosition()` got called.

Comment: yes i figure that but, I dont know how to do it, the page is first execute the body and after that the function.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function getLocation() {

    if (navigator.geolocation) {
            navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(displayLocation);
    }else {
                   alert("Geolocation API is not supported in your browser.");
    }
}

    function displayLocation(position) {
       latitude = position.coords.latitude;
       longitude = position.coords.longitude;
       alert('aaab:' +longitude);
    }
```